# Snapping to orthographic views on MacOS

Tags: 3d-view, snapping, orthographic

Like the title says, I am wondering if anyone knows how to snap orthographically on MacOS without having to press on the gizmo in the top right (or use the numpad)

On windows, while tumbling the view, this is a simple press on ALT.. however on mac, the option button just seems to halt movement..

hope anyone has the answer.

Comment: Have you checked Preferences > Keymap assignments? There you can find all shortcuts or create yours.

Answer (score 0):

Test your problem:

Press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>. Then press  <kbd>MMB</kbd>  and then  <kbd>Alt</kbd> while orbiting.  If the function is working, it should lock every 15 degrees in top view.  Test both the left and right  <kbd>alt option</kbd> keys.

When I do this, I see this message at the bottom of my screen:

[image]

If it still isn't working then go to preferences.  It may help to click off auto-save preferences temporarily so you can test out a few changes.

[image]

In the Key-Binding search window, type in "Rotate".  Open the 3D View, Rotate View options, and change these controls beside "Axis Snap" to another key.:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thanks for your response but thats not what i meant. I will try to exlain it again... when tumbling the view (rotating around your scene, objects) on windows you press ALT to snap orthographically.... on mac it should be the option key.. but its not working

Comment: thanks that was the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + Middle mouse dragging in some direction rotates the view to closest orthographic view on Windows, so that should be <kbd>whatever-replaces-alt-in-MacOS</kbd> + middle mouse dragging on MacOS as well.

[image]

This is actually way more intuitive than numpad since you don't need to think what side is what axis.